# Anaconda Spyder cannot find Qt WebEngine ICU

Tags: python, qt, anaconda, spyder

After an update, my spyder installation no longer starts. I currently have 5.1.5 installed and have also tried the latest version of 4 with the same issue.

Here's the error message it returns:

```
ERROR conda.cli.main_run:execute(41): `conda run spyder` failed. (See above for error)
Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file
Qt WebEngine ICU data not found at /home/main-builder/pkgwork/pkg/anaconda/opt/anaconda/resources. Trying parent directory...
Qt WebEngine ICU data not found at /home/main-builder/pkgwork/pkg/anaconda/opt/anaconda. Trying application directory...
Qt WebEngine ICU data not found at /opt/anaconda/libexec. Trying fallback directory... The application MAY NOT work.
Path override failed for key base::DIR_QT_LIBRARY_DATA and path '/home/trevor/.QtWebEngineProcess'
Installed Qt WebEngine locales directory not found at location /home/main-builder/pkgwork/pkg/anaconda/opt/anaconda/translations/qtwebengine_locales. Trying application directory...
Qt WebEngine locales directory not found at location /opt/anaconda/libexec/qtwebengine_locales. Trying fallback directory... Translations MAY NOT not be correct.
Path override failed for key ui::DIR_LOCALES and path '/home/trevor/.QtWebEngineProcess'
[0531/095725.150666:ERROR:icu_util.cc(178)] Invalid file descriptor to ICU data received.
[0531/095725.150692:FATAL:content_main_runner.cc(691)] Check failed: base::i18n::InitializeICU(). 
#0 0x7fa964a9e0be <unknown>
#1 0x7fa964ab06c2 <unknown>
#2 0x7fa964a87068 <unknown>
#3 0x7fa964a82519 <unknown>
#4 0x7fa96443d49a QtWebEngine::processMain()
#5 0x55c1c3c81d74 <unknown>
#6 0x7fa96273b290 <unknown>
#7 0x7fa96273b34a __libc_start_main
#8 0x55c1c3c81dd4 <unknown>

[134606:134606:0531/095725.232330:FATAL:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(182)] Check failed: ReceiveFixedMessage(fds[0], kZygoteBootMessage, sizeof(kZygoteBootMessage), &boot_pid). 
#0 0x7f9354f130be <unknown>
#1 0x7f9354f256c2 <unknown>
#2 0x7f9354c8f987 <unknown>
#3 0x7f9354c8eb07 <unknown>
#4 0x7f9354c8ee96 <unknown>
#5 0x7f9354a399a1 <unknown>
#6 0x7f9354a3d727 <unknown>
#7 0x7f93548cf542 <unknown>
#8 0x7f93548cf718 <unknown>
#9 0x7f93548c6681 <unknown>
#10 0x7f93548c6732 QtWebEngineCore::WebContentsAdapter::WebContentsAdapter()
#11 0x7f9359173376 <unknown>
#12 0x7f93591710c4 <unknown>
#13 0x7f9359171252 QWebEnginePage::QWebEnginePage()
#14 0x7f93591a2689 sipQWebEnginePage::sipQWebEnginePage()
#15 0x7f93591a2812 init_type_QWebEnginePage
#16 0x7f935a4548d4 <unknown>
#17 0x5651e2098d5f _PyObject_MakeTpCall
#18 0x5651e213280a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault
#19 0x5651e20f3663 _PyEval_EvalCode
#20 0x5651e20f43c4 _PyFunction_Vectorcall
#21 0x5651e20def4e _PyObject_FastCallDictTstate
#22 0x5651e20e8b79 slot_tp_init
#23 0x5651e2098d5f _PyObject_MakeTpCall
#24 0x5651e2133735 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault
#25 0x5651e20f3663 _PyEval_EvalCode
#26 0x5651e20f4354 _PyFunction_Vectorcall
#27 0x5651e20deeca _PyObject_FastCallDictTstate
#28 0x5651e20e8b79 slot_tp_init
#29 0x5651e2098d5f _PyObject_MakeTpCall
#30 0x5651e213280a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault
#31 0x5651e20f3663 _PyEval_EvalCode
#32 0x5651e20f4354 _PyFunction_Vectorcall
#33 0x5651e20deeca _PyObject_FastCallDictTstate
#34 0x5651e20e8b79 slot_tp_init
#35 0x5651e2098d5f _PyObject_MakeTpCall
#36 0x5651e213280a _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault
#37 0x5651e20f3663 _PyEval_EvalCode
#38 0x5651e20f43c4 _PyFunction_Vectorcall
#39 0x5651e20def4e _PyObject_FastCallDictTstate
#40 0x5651e20e8b79 slot_tp_init
#41 0x5651e2098d5f _PyObject_MakeTpCall
#42 0x5651e2133735 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault
#43 0x5651e20f3663 _PyEval_EvalCode
#44 0x5651e20f4da9 method_vectorcall
#45 0x5651e205b58e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault.cold.2984
#46 0x5651e20f3663 _PyEval_EvalCode
#47 0x5651e20f43c4 _PyFunction_Vectorcall
#48 0x5651e20def4e _PyObject_FastCallDictTstate
#49 0x5651e20e8b79 slot_tp_init
#50 0x5651e2098d5f _PyObject_MakeTpCall
#51 0x5651e2133735 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault
#52 0x5651e20f3663 _PyEval_EvalCode
#53 0x5651e20f4ca4 method_vectorcall
#54 0x5651e205c755 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault.cold.2984
#55 0x5651e20f3663 _PyEval_EvalCode
#56 0x5651e20f4da9 method_vectorcall
#57 0x5651e205b58e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault.cold.2984
#58 0x5651e20f3663 _PyEval_EvalCode
#59 0x5651e20f4ca4 method_vectorcall
#60 0x5651e205c755 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault.cold.2984
#61 0x5651e20f4284 _PyFunction_Vectorcall

/tmp/tmpc5j7hggd: line 3: 134606 Aborted                 (core dumped) spyder
```

this occurred after a package update where spyder was update from version 4 to 5. This was previously solved by moving /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 to the /opt/ directory with version 4, but this solution does not seem to work with 5.

`$ Conda list qt` returns the following

```
# packages in environment at /opt/anaconda:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
pyqt                      5.9.2            py39h2531618_6
qt                        5.9.7                h5867ecd_1
qtawesome                 1.0.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
qtconsole                 5.3.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
qtpy                      2.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-qthelp      1.0.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
```

Additional details:
OS: Garuda Linux (Arch)

Any help would be happily appreciated, thank you!

Edit: the following forced installs solved the problem.
https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/qt-webengine
https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/

conda install directly did not but using the conda-forge variants did.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) This usually happens if you're using an old Linux distro. So perhaps it could be solved by updating it.

Comment: Hi Carlos. Thank you for the suggestion. The issue first appeared after an update though. I regularly update my distro and Garuda/Arch are fairly up-to-date distros. 

I did solve the problem somehow by uninstalling spyder and then force installing qt-webengine and pyqt-webengine from conda forge:
https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/qt-webengine
https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/

Comment: Great! Glad to know you were able to solve your problem.